# Entering values to dataframe with numpy.where

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to entering values to dataframe based on a condition. I have movie attribute columns like 'AttributeHorror' or 'AttributeRomance' etc. Columns are filled with NaN. If the condition is met, it have to replace with 1. if not, 0.

I tried the following code but it didnt return correct.

```py
film_data['AttributeOlumsuz'] 
       =np.where(film_data['FilmAttributes1']=='Olumsuz', '1', '0')


film_data['AttributeSiddet'] = np.where(film_data['FilmAttributes1']=='Siddet', '1', '0')


film_data['AttributeAltyazi'] = 
np.where(film_data['FilmAttributes1']=='Altyazili', '1', '0')

film_data['AttributeGerilim'] = 
np.where(film_data['FilmAttributes1']=='Gerilim', '1', '0')
```

This code fills every cell incorrect. Where am i making mistake?

Comment: Could you explain how it is incorrect? What do you get instead of your expected result?

Comment: it fills with 0 or 1, thats okay. but they're not the expected counts of values. i thought it might be rewrite on same cells but i couldnt get out of it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple list comprehension should work.

There are two parts:

1) iterate over the original values

2) list comprehension conditional assignment

These are commented in the code below.

```py
film_data['AttributeOlumsuz'] = [
    '1' if v=='olumsuz' else '0' #2 list comprehension conditional assignment here
    for v in film_data['FilmAttributes1'] #1 iterate over original values here
]
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution. With your code, i understand my mistake. actually, i have 6 attributes like 'FilmAttributes2', 'FilmAttributes3' and their codes are same with above. They update everytime AttributeOlumsuz column. So my question is, can i add 'else if' condition like (else if v=!0 or v!=1). i tried but it returns with error.

Answer (score 0):

If `numpy.where()` does not work.

Assuming you are reading your data using pandas.DataFrame, you can try:

**First Possible Solution:**

`df.loc[df['AttributeOlumsuz'] == 'Olumsuz', 'Tagger_Column'] = '1'`

**Second Possible Solution:**

You can also use `.map()` method.

```
your_dict = {'Olumsuz': '1'}
df['Tagger_Column'] = df['AttributeOlumsuz'].map(your_dict)
```

Result of `map` for `False` entries is `NaN`, if you don't like that you can use `fillna` with parameter equals to whatever value you please:

```
df['Tagger_Column'].fillna(value = '0') # to replicate your condition in numpy.where() above
```

Comment: Show a snippet of your DataFrame and the expected output, so we can work this out :))

Comment: Let me change my answer, and try again. :))